# Image in responsive inline div changes position of neighboring div

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, flexbox

I have a responsive div, split into two vertically. These are set to display inline, side-by-side horizontally, unless the viewport shrinks below 400px, then they stack vertically.

Everything works fine when the two child divs contain text only - but an image in the left-hand child div will cause the right-hand child div to drop: http://jsfiddle.net/2o9ryj93/.

I'm not sure why. Can anyone help me out? Thanks for your time.

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.wrapper:after {
    padding-top: 70%;
    display: block;
    content: '';
}
.main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}
#left,
#right {
    font-family: serif;
    line-height: 150%;
    font-size: 2.2vw;
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 40%;
    height: 90%;
    background-color: #edeeeb;
    padding: 5%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2o9ryj93/1/)

Add CSS:

```
#left, #right{float:left;}
```